# I can't see all my Facebook friends in the Empathy Chat

Tags: empathy, facebook

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I connected Empathy with my Facebook account.
It adds only a couple contacts, while I know that from the browser, many of my friends are online.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have almost de same problem with my Yahoo contacts.

Comment: Saw the same trouble, started about 1 week ago. I didn't solve it. It broke in Pidgin at the same time. Pidgin now requires "connect server" in the advanced settings to also be set to chat.facebook.com to work correctly. I fooled around with similar settings in empathy this morning and found the work around in the short term, unfortunately, is to use pidgin.

Comment: Since the release of FBMessenger FB plugin does not work

Comment: Try removing your account and adding it back. That happened to me after the upgrade and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

May be your current version of empathy chat is not completely compatible with UBUNTU 13.04

Try downloading a newer version of Empathy chat from the Ubuntu software center...

Hope this helps....

Feel free to comment for queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubutu Raring and the most recent Empathy version 3.6.4. I have the issue facebook contacts don't show up. I reinstalled account plugin facebook (also the newest version) in Synaptic package manager and the problem solved.